# Resizing UICollectionView based on number of cells

Tags: uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, uicollectionviewlayout

I have a `UICollection` view with 1-4 cells, and underneath a `UITextField` is constrained to the bottom of it.

I want to be able to resize the `UICollectionView` so if it has 1 or 2 cells, the height of the `UICollectionView` is this height, otherwise given it has 3 or 4 cells, the height is the 2 * cell height + vertical spacing.

Is there a simple way to do this without all of the maths? It seems odd to have the constraints system and still have to do this laborious maths to size a `UIView`.

Thanks as always